# Rails Baffling Result Parsing Array Param Sent Via Curl Multipart POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, post, multipartform-data

Please explain this, or provide a more-correct solution.

```
class Store < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores
end
```

I have several books in the database. I'd like to create a new store with several books in it.

The following few curl commands result in Rails parsing an empty array for params[book_ids]:

```
curl -F "author[book_ids[]]=[1,2]" -F "author[description]=some description" localhost:3000/authors.multipart
    Started POST "/authors.multipart" for 127.0.0.1 at ...
    Processing by AuthorsController#create as MULTIPART
    Parameters: {"author"=>{"gesture_ids"=>[], "description"=>"some description", @headers ...

curl -F "author[book_ids[]]=\"[1,2]\"" -F "author[description]=some description" localhost:3000/authors.multipart
    Started POST "/authors.multipart" for 127.0.0.1 at ...
    Processing by AuthorsController#create as MULTIPART
    Parameters: {"author"=>{"gesture_ids"=>[], "description"=>"some description", @headers ...

curl -F "author[book_ids[]]=1" -F "author[book_ids[]]=2" -F "author[description]=some description" localhost:3000/authors.multipart
    Started POST "/authors.multipart" for 127.0.0.1 at ...
    Processing by AuthorsController#create as MULTIPART
    Parameters: {"author"=>{"gesture_ids"=>[], "description"=>"some description", @headers ...
```

But the following command does the trick:

```
curl -F "author[book_ids[]=1" -F "author[book_ids[]=2" -F "author[description]=some description" localhost:3000/authors.multipart
    Started POST "/authors.multipart" for 127.0.0.1 at ...
    Processing by AuthorsController#create as MULTIPART
    Parameters: {"author"=>{"gesture_ids"=>["1","2"], "description"=>"some description", @headers ...
```

As you can see, the command is a missing a right brace in a couple of places, but it works. Checking the trace, curl is indeed sending the following for the first book.

```
0000: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
=> Send data, 502 bytes (0x1f6)
0000: --------------------------538dd4bc2333141c
002c: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="store[book_ids[]"
0068: 
006a: 1
006f: --------------------------538dd4bc2333141c
```

Comment: have you tried using the correct syntax of `author[book_ids][]=1`? The syntax in this case is `wrapper[key] = value` (like you have for description) so for an `Array` we state that it is an `Array` of values `wrapper[key][]` then the `=` appends the value to the `Array`. Write now `author[book_ids[]]=[1,2]` would technically be parsed as `author: {book_ids: []} = [1,2]` which is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Ahah, so the indication of the array [] goes after the wrapper[key] syntax. Yes, that works, thanks. If you turn your comment into a reply, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax of `author[book_ids][]=1`

The syntax in this case is `wrapper[key] = value` (like you have for description) so for an `Array` we state that it is an `Array` of values `wrapper[key][]` then the `=` appends the value to the `Array`.

Write now `author[book_ids[]]=[1,2]` would technically be parsed as `author: {book_ids: []} = [1,2]` which is clearly incorrect and the parser just ignores the assignment.